# Moving data from One kendoui grid to other, both the grids have different models

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

Presenly I have requirement in which i have to pas data between two kendoui grids.
My problem is the datamodel of two grids are different.

My source grid has two columns
My destination grid had two columns from source grid and some additional columns.

Below is what i have tried: I am unable to insert the selected records from source to destination grid.

My source grid defination:

```
 <div id="SearchADUserGrid">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModelADUsers>()
              .Name("kADUser")
              .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Template(@<text></text>)
                                        .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsSelected ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginName);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.UserDisplayName);

                  })
              .AutoBind(false)
              .DataSource(ds => ds
                               .Ajax()
                               .Read(read =>
                                {
                                read.Action("GetADUser", "ManageUsers");
                                read.Data("AdditionalData");
                                })
                               .ServerOperation(false)
               )
             .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
        )

        <a href="#" id="btnAddusers" class="k-button">Add Selected Users</a>
    </div>
```

My destination Grid definition

```
 <div id="AvailableUserRoleSection">

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModelUserRoles>()
              .Name("kUserRoles")
              .Columns(columns =>{
                      columns.Bound(p => p.UserRoleId).Hidden(true);
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Users.UserLoginName).Title("StaffID");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Users.UserDisplayName).Title("StaffName");
                      columns.Bound(p => p.Roles).ClientTemplate("#: Roles.RoleName #").Title("Assigned Role");
                      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
              })
              .AutoBind(true)
              .Editable(editable =>{
                      editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
                      editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Do you really want to remove the user from role assigned?");
              })
              .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a href='javascript: void(0)'  onclick='createRow()' title='assign'>Assign User Roles</a>"))
              .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
              .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
              .DataSource(ds =>{
                      ds.Ajax()
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Events(events =>{
                                      //events.Error("onError");
                               events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");

                         })
                        .Model(model => {
                                   model.Id(p => p.UserRoleId);
                                   model.Field(p => p.Users.UserLoginName).Editable(false);
                                   model.Field(p => p.Users.UserDisplayName).Editable(false);
                                   model.Field(p => p.Roles).DefaultValue(
                                                 ViewData["defaultRoles"] as FMSApps.Models.ViewModelRoles);

                         })
                         .Read(read => read.Action("GetUserRoles", "ManageUsers"))
                         .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateUserRoles", "ManageUsers"))
                         .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteUserRoles", "ManageUsers"));
                      })

)
```

here i am checking which rows are checked in my source grid:

```
  $('#kADUser').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {

        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        var grid = $('#kADUser').data().kendoGrid;
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
        dataItem.set('IsSelected', checked);
    })
```

Then On button click i need to move the selected row from source grid to destination grid

```
    function moveGridRows(sourceGridName, destinationGridName) {
        var sourceGrid = $("#" + sourceGridName).data("kendoGrid");
        var destinationGrid = $("#" + destinationGridName).data("kendoGrid");


        var selectedRows = [];
        var rowsForRemove = [];
        //get the selected rows from the source grid
        $("#" + sourceGridName + " tbody tr").each(function () {
            var currentDataItem = sourceGrid.dataItem($(this));
            //insert your custom check if the row is selected here
            if (currentDataItem.IsSelected) {
                selectedRows.push(currentDataItem);
                rowsForRemove.push($(this));
            }
        })



        //insert selected rows using DataSource insert method
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            var currentRecord = selectedRows[i];
            //set the id to 0
            currentRecord.UserRoleId = 0;
            //destinationGrid.dataSource.insert(currentRecord);
            destinationGrid.dataSource.add(currentRecord)
```

> ****IT IS BREAKING AT THE ABOVE LINE*****????

```
        }

        //remove the already inserted rows
        for (var i = 0; i < rowsForRemove.length; i++) {
            sourceGrid.removeRow(rowsForRemove[i]);
        }
    }


    $('#btnAddusers').click(function () {
        debugger;
        moveGridRows("kADUser","kUserRoles")
    });
```

Please help and let me know if I have to anything else to make it work or anywhere i am going wrong.

Comment: Can anybody has any idea on this please share, i am really looking for a solution.

Comment: I am able to find out the solution for my problem and my grids are working perfectly